# Css Content attribute with elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am working on a small project.

I wish to add an anchor tag `<a>` inside another element using the css content attribute and the :after pseudo.

e.g.

```
.classname:after { content: '<a>hello</a>'; } 
// this will print "<a>hello</a>"
```

What I need it to do is make it have a working anchor tag, pointing to a given `href`.
I know you can use something like this `content: attr(title);` so it will use `.classname` `title` attribute as a text, I don't know if this is even possible but, it would be cool if it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the CSS `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements to insert HTML elements. To add HTML elements you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: I know I can with javascript, Just wondered if it was possible... but I guess this answers the question :)

Answer (score 1):

You cant im afraid. You have to use javascript :(

A quick example of putting a link into a p with the id of myP tho... and a variable for a url (which could be obtained from any value really)...

```
var myUrl = "http://www.glcreations.co.uk";

document.getElementById("myP").innerHTML = "<a href='" + myUrl + "'>A link for you to click on</a>";
```